# sql where statement help. if 0 then choose all

Tags: sql, where-clause

I got a country tabel that defines what country you are from, 1-5.. And i have written an droplist for one to choose witch country you want to search it. And i got one section in the dropdown list where i want to choose search all. And if country is 0 then i want it to be no restricted like it is in the code bellow where (country = @country and town = @town) i just want it to be (town = @town) etc

```
   IF @Case = 1 BEGIN
                SELECT
                    Rec_Id,
                    Country,
                    PostalCode,
                    Town,
                    Lat,
                    Lng


                FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode AS PC WITH (NOLOCK)
                WHERE 
                 (town = @town AND country = @country) or (postalcode = @postalcode AND country = @country)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just send a null for @country when the "select all countries" option is set and then

use a where clause like so:
WHERE (@country is null or country = @country)

Edit: Just to clarify things. Why I would use a null value is because imho that signifies "no filter for that parameter" better than using an arbitrary value.

Comment: (country = null and town = @town) like this?

Comment: No, like  WHERE (@country is null or country = @country) AND (town = @town or postalcode = @postalcode)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're passing the @Country variable with a possible value of 1 - 5 but also a possible value of 0 that equals all countries.

Try using something like this:

```
IF @Case = 1 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT REC_ID, 
             COUNTRY, 
             POSTALCODE, 
             TOWN, 
             LAT, 
             LNG 
      FROM   DBO.TBL_POSTALCODE AS PC WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE  ( COUNTRY = @country 
                OR @country = 0 ) 
             AND ( TOWN = @town 
                    OR POSTALCODE = @postalcode ) 
  END
```

Comment: I got it to work (country = null or town = @town) or (country = null or postalcode = @postalcode)

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson, what RDBMS are you using?  Usually writing '= null' is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add another condition to your `WHERE`:

```
...
WHERE
  (@selectAllCountries = 1 OR country = @country)
  AND (town = @town OR postalcode = @postalcode)
```

I'm obviously assuming you've got a `@selectAllCountries` variable which is either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work setting (country = null or town = @town) or (country = null or postalcode = @postalcode).

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You should **accept** your own answer if this solved it for you (with the "V" icon to the left of the answer), and also upvote any other answers that you found useful.  Thanks.